# How do I access a React component's state from global?

Tags: reactjs

I'm not using Redux or Flux or any framework for that matter.
I have a React component that I want to reuse for multiple pages.

It has a state to control it's visiblity.

How can I reach into the component, and trigger the state from a standard HTML button?

Most answers point to Redux/Flux/MobX, but they're for SPA, but mine is a plain page with no frameworks mounting a React component.

Comment: I would add an hidden `input` to store the visible value, the use `ReactDOM` to get it

Comment: Is that `standard HTML Button` rendered within a React Component or in HTML file as hard-coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `standard HTML Button` is not rendered within a `React Component`, you can listen HTML Elements' events from React Components. Say we have static button in our HTML file:

```
<button id="buttonA">Toggle Visibility</button>
```

Inside our React Component, We can listen click event for this element and update our state to set something's visibility:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // here we are listening our hard-coded static HTML Element's click event
    // And update our state based on this.
    document.getElementById('buttonA').addEventListener("click", e => {
      this.setState({hidden: !this.state.hidden})
    })
  }
```

Here is a [working example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/aoguzhan/pen/ayKBRB). You can play with it.

Comment: @resting Glad to help!